# How to give spacing between rows in Data grid(form view) in LiveCode

Tags: livecode

I am new in LiveCode,so facing lots of troubles.I am populating a data grid in LiveCode.so getting simultaneous Rows but i need some spacing between the rows.how can i achieve that,
can any one help me in that ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following link is to our LiveCode Datagird lessons portal which should be able to help you with this request

http://lessons.runrev.com/m/datagrid

Comment: Neil, I have noticed that you have posted quite a few links to lessons. Actually, the idea of StackOverflow is that you don't need to go to another website to get the answer. You're supposed to post the info here.

Comment: The comment from @Mark is spot on.  See this Meta Stack Overflow post for the community guidelines on "link-only" answers: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).  Do your best to summarize the solution here, and include relevant code snippets.

Comment: Also, community members have gone through and removed the "signature block" from your answers.  See [this Help Center article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), specifically the section "*Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings*"